# Programmatically declaring document as record in share point 2016 using java client?

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-online

I want to know if there is any REST API or SOAP service available to declare document as record in online share-point/ share-point 2016. I have read on a blog that new package released by CSOM (version 16.1.4727.1200) allows you to do it.